# How can i insert a watermark to my banner in a website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a banner inside my website and I want to add a watermark to it without the need to edit the image. I have the watermark logo file ready, but I need the right HTML code to do the above.

If any can help me please, share the correct HTML code that I need to insert anywhere inside my website to display the watermarked banner.

Try to make the code clear and add some comments so that I know where to place my banner and my watermark URLs.

An example is provided in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: show your code pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This site is for *specific* programming-related questions. This question is much too broad to be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to insert the banner first on the page and then insert the logo and with some CSS you position the logo on the top of the banner. here the code you need.

```
<div>
<img style="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjp6.jpg" width="1366" height="auto">
<img style="     position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 50px;
" src="https://optic-communications.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/logologo.png" width="150px" height="auto">
</div>
```

The above code will insert your banner then it will insert another picture "logologo.png" on the top of your banner in a specific position with these coordinates Bottom:200px and left:50px, you can move the logo by changing these value. Bottom means how much the logo must be far from the bottom, in our case its 200px, so if you want to move the logo up increase the 200px.

Make sure to change your logo URL to the logo you want to use.

Give it a try and let me know. you can find the source code here: https://jsfiddle.net/s29x5mv7/1/